# How to make tablayout fragment fit INSIDE viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, height, floating-action-button

I've got a simple fragment for my tablayout/viewpager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".pkgFragment.InputDataOverviewFragment"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    >


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abToolBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
        >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tbMenuIconWithTitle"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            >
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/svInputdata"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:defaultQueryHint="@string/search_incometypes"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:searchIcon="@null"
                app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                app:submitBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutInputDataTypes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="@color/BrightYellowCrayola"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_below="@id/tabLayoutInputDataTypes"
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerInputDataTypes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my fragment which is shown when its selected on the tablayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

    >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvListIncomeType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/zero_margin_when_normal"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/zero_margin_when_normal"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAddDeleteIncomeType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_incometype"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_person_add_24"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/BrightYellowCrayola" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The issue is that the height of my fragment matches my parent fragment and thats why the fragment is height is not fit exactly inside my viewpager:

[image]

As you can seen, the floating action button dissapears halfway below and the first toolbar is basically dragged up and it does not appear entirely.

What would be the correct solution to handle the height issue in tablayouts with fragment?

Comment: for me it looks like you are using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for your `Activity`

Comment: @snachmsm hmm no, i only use it for my tablayoutfragment (seen below) I also tried removing it before but the outcome did not changed unfourtantly.

Comment: This couldn't happen with the shared layouts.. Do have any java/kotlin code? Please share it.. Also share the style xml file

Comment: @Zain I posted my solution down below. It seemed it was a layout issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two lines I removed (currently) in order to make it work:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

and

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

I'll keep u updated if it was a smart idea to remove it.